# SQL: Increment ID only for new rows based on the count

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Requirement: Generate new ID from the MAX ID for those Name doesn't exist in the Target table and has count >1

Below is the Source data, The yellow highlighted are new rows, Those with count >1 are incremented with a new ID, and those with count =1 defaults to FM00000001

The expected result is highlighted in yellow in the Target table

I have generated the existing ID manually for one time , as I have to automate daily jobs so I need to generate incremental ID from MAX ID for those count >1

[image]

```
   with src as (
            select '121 MEDICAL PLACE'      as Label ,  1 as cnt 
            union all 
            select '16TH STREET COMMUNITY'  as Label ,  1 as cnt  
            union all 
            select '19TH AVENUE CLINIC'     as Label ,  2 as cnt
            union all 
            select '1ST CLASS URGENT CARE'  as Label ,  3 as cnt 
            union all 
            select '160 DORADO BCH'         as Label ,  2 as cnt 
            union all 
            select 'APPLETREE LN'           as Label ,  4 as cnt 
            union all 
            select 'KNOLLWOOD LN'           as Label ,  1 as cnt
)
select * from src 

with tgt as (
            select '121 MEDICAL PLACE'      as Label ,  'FM00000001' as ID 
            union all 
            select '16TH STREET COMMUNITY'  as Label ,  'FM00000001'as ID 
            union all 
            select '19TH AVENUE CLINIC'     as Label ,  'FM00000002'as ID 
            union all 
            select '1ST CLASS URGENT CARE'  as Label ,  'FM00000003' as ID 
)
select * from tgt
```

Comment: so for example for 'APPLETREE LN', you already have count 1 in target table and now you have count 4 so Id will be updated to 5?is that correct?

Comment: No , for APPLETREE LN I see count >1 , that means this has to be incremented from MAXID of the target table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok If I understand correctly , here is how you can do it :

```
select * 
   , 'FM'+ LPAD(case when cnt =1 then cnt else count(case when cnt > 1 then 1 end) over (order by OrderColumn ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) + 1 end, 8,0) as ID
from table
```

for reference: [Window Functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html#label-window-frame-usage-notes)

Comment: ERROR: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause

Comment: @kar hmm... what about now see updated answer? that's weird because documentation says : If no window frame is specified, the default is the following cumulative window frame (in accordance with the ANSI standard):`RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`

Comment: Just struck me if there is a row that already existed in the target table which is previously as count =1 then later I got from source as count > 1, How do I make sure to update those rows with incremental ID

Comment: I would join two table and compare the calculated Id from source with ID from target , if they don't match then update